# Is it possible to add an extra element to an object[] array if it has already been instantiated?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Assume the following code as an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object objects = new Object();
        objects.object1 = new ObjectList[4];
    }
    
    public class Object
    {
        public ObjectList[] object1;
    }
    
    public class ObjectList
    {
        public string name;
    }
```

Let's say the user wants to input another element in the object1[] array later on with a Console.ReadLine() - would this be possible or is the array length after initialization final? In other words, can the same object array be deleted or overwritten to contain 5 elements instead of 4 (perhaps utilizing a temporary array to transfer the separate objects within the array).

Comment: No, but you can use a generic List<T> - it's the preferred way. It has an add method.

Comment: `Array.Resize(ref objects.object1, objects.object1.Length + 1);`

Comment: Of course it can, but as others have stated, there are better constructs to use if you need a "dynamic size". Side note: Since you made `object1` directly accessible with PUBLIC, we can also make it point to null, making it instantly lose everything. PUBLIC is a bad, bad idea...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Would you always make attributes private at all times? Or are properties solely used?

Comment: The academic answer is yes, attributes should always be private. Wrap them in a public property if they need to be accessible from the outside. It's more work, but an important habit to build.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but no. Although you can resize the array and copy all the elements into it, thats not how it should be done, because of performance issues and simply because arrays are meant to hold exact ammount of elements.

One of correct ways of doing this is to use `List<T>` and from here you can filter it using LINQ, add elements, remove elements,...

Comment: I think it is important to note that `List<T>` is designed to be more generic, but it will still create new arrays and copy old arrays internally at certain size boundaries. If you are initializing the list to a certain size (capacity), adding one entry will be just like resizing an array.

Comment: @NetMage I was looking for an answer like this. So we are basically forced, if we encounter dynamically sized arrays (where the user has the possibility of adding elements ad finitum) to create a new array each time as we can not effictively override the old ones?

Comment: I agree, but we could also ask a question "Can I store numerical values in string?"... answer would be yes, but just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. It's important to know what certain data structures are used for and where to use a proper one. Makes code performance and readability better, prevents "code smells",...

Comment: @Aleksandar There is no reason to prefer an array over a `List<T>` in any situation (except when micro-optimizing), but especially when the collection grows or shrinks dynamically. `List<T>` internally uses an array, but it resizes the array when growing by double the existing size to optimize for multiple growth occurrences by reducing resizing to Log2 times. I am not sure what you mean by "effectively override". `Array.Resize` creates a new array, and modifies the variable passed to point to the new array. Any existing references to the old array continue to point to the old array.

Comment: @Aleksandar If you need to update all references to an array that might be stored when you resize an array, then you need to add a layer of indirection, and that is what `List<T>` does for you.

Comment: What I took issue with is your statement "because of performance issues" as if `List<T>` does not have similar performance issues and others that arrays do not have (e.g. every member reference is a double redirection or looping through the members is not optimized). Also LINQ works just as well with arrays as with `List<T>` so that isn't a differentiator either. A simple statement that `List<T>` handles dynamic resizing better than arrays would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Resize(ref objects.object1, 5);`

It resizes your array (copies elements from old one to new one).